# How to set the bar width to a fixed value in Shinobi Charts?

Tags: ios, graph, charts, bar-chart, shinobi

I am trying to get used to Shinobi charts developed for iOS. I've downloaded trial version on same and trying to plot some sample charts using it. The charts look pretty good in demo apps. But one thing I noticed that while using class SChartColumnSeries to plot bar chart, the width of the bars is adjusted according to the frame available to plot the chart. I want it to be fixed (say 20 pixels) regardless of number of bars present and if the width required is more than what is assigned (while assigning frame to the chart) then only some part of the chart will be visible and user can scroll the chart to view remaining bars (This is possible in Core Plot). How can I achieve this using Shinobi charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Shinobi, but it's not a simple case of setting a fixed width property I'm afraid. I've just tried to do this though and its isn't too complicated!

My advice would be to set up the chart like this:

```
chart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[chart setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[chart setDatasource:d];

[chart setXAxis:[SChartNumberAxis new]];
[chart setYAxis:[SChartNumberAxis new]];
[[chart xAxis] setEnableGesturePanning:YES];
[[chart xAxis] setEnableGestureZooming:NO];

[chart.xAxis setDefaultRange:[[SChartNumberRange alloc] initWithMinimum:@5 andMaximum:@10]];
```

The most important part is the last 3 lines. By turning zooming off you allow your charts to have a fixed zoom level, meaning the bars stay the same width. You can turn the panning on to allow users to scroll to see different bars.

The last line sets the default range. Here, i've just set it to values between 5 and 10. That means that the chart displays values between 5 and 10 along the x-axis.

By doing the above, this means that your columns will have a fixed width! You might have to do some tweaking and / or calculation depending on how many data points you have, in order to find out what you have to set your default range to. If they are variable for example, you will need to take into account the number of data points, the padding between the columns and inter column padding and the number of pixels you have available).

I realise this is quite a simplified answer but it should give you a good starting point!

Comment: Thanks man...will try this out. I am afraid that demos with Shinobi framework doesn't reveal all of its features.